# 2001 f150 excessive spindle, bearing(inner and outer) and rotor wear

Tags: ford, brake-rotor, bearing

Since Jan 2017 I have paid the repair bills for replacement spindles, rotor's and bearing twice on each side. And the parts are not cheap. Is there something I'm doing wrong when replacing these parts. I hasn't mattered if we used factory OEM or after market. Other then cost. My vehicle is a 2001 RWD 4.6 Ford F150.  It is driven an average of 400 miles a day, 6 days a week. Any one out there with an idea.

ps. I'm replacing the right front rotor and bearings today, which I had inspected 5 day ago when I replaced to left front side.  Help

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your issues. What are the symptoms you are experiencing and what makes you think you have to replace the rotor and bearings?

Comment: Are you over torquing the bearing nut?

Answer (score 1):

I have performed this procedure successfully twice on my truck. It's a common failure, but the parts should last at least 150000 miles of normal driving.

You have mentioned replacing spindles, rotors, and bearings on a wheel. This is common and the correct course of action for a failed bearing. Here are some suggestions

1. Are you replacing the rotor seal? If not, the bearing is essentially open to the environment. It will not last long at all unless a new seal is used each time. This keeps dirt and dust out.
2. Are you following the correct procedure for torque-ing the wheel bearing? If you're used to working on vehicles, it is counter intuitive. The final torque is "17 in-lbs", which might as well just be finger tight. Higher torque values will cause bearing failure almost immediately. Consult the Ford service manual for the procedure.
3. Consider using scrapyard spindles. There are plenty of good spindles in scrapyards, often for less than 10% of the OEM price I was quoted by Ford.
4. Are you packing the bearing with the correct type and amount of grease? It is very difficult to use too much grease. Any excess grease will just wind up in the space between the bearings and the spindle. You can pack far more grease into them than you would think. Too little grease leads to premature failure of the bearing.

Comment: Tapered roller bearings should last for a long time.  It sounds like you are not repacking the bearings, torquing them incorrectly, or not replacing the wheel seal (or all of the above).  You should not have to replace the spindle unless it is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to consider:

- Are your rotors/pads wearing unevenly, or warping?
- Do you hear a variable hum coming from the front end while on the highway?
- Do you feel a wobble?

It's hard to guess as to why you're replacing so often.  But, if you're incorrectly 'pressing' the new bearings that could lead to a lot of vibration.